# Is there a more efficient way to replace multiple strings in a html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, replace

first of all please excuse my bad title. Don't know how to name it.
This is a student project. My task is to explore/examine many, fairly large, texts in a web app. 
But this is not important, that's anyway the way how it needs to be done. 
The strings that needs to be replaced are stored in a json file. I'm iterating throw the file with

```
$.each(stringList, function(index, value) {
var isInContent = $('#myContent').text().indexOf(index) > -1;
if (isInContent) {... replaceString(index); ...}
}
```

And to replace the string I use

```
$('#myContent :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace(index, myNewString);
});
```

It works as it should. But it's a bit slow. I think because it's loading for every replace the $('#content') and writes the whole $('#content') after the replace back to the html. 
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Now for each stringlist, you are parsing DOM. This will  slowdown execution. Assign text from $('#myContent').text() to a variable and then pass this variable inside $each function.

Comment: @VishalPawar Hi, thank you for the answer. So you mean I should replace $('#myContent :not(script)').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }) with for example myVar and then simply do myVar.replaceWith(...)? Ok I will try that.

Comment: @VishalPawar OK replacing $('#myContent').text() works, but I don't know how I can replace $('#myContent :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace(index, myNewString);
}); Do you have an idea?